# how do i extract numbers from each word in a string in python

Tags: python

This is my string

`data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'`

***Expected Result:
[122, 125, 55, 58, 25]***

> Try1:

```
data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'
s = re.search(r"\d+(\.\d+)?", data)
print(s.group(0))
```

*Output: 122*

> Try2:

```
data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'
s = [int(s) for s in data.split() if s.isdigit()]
print(s)
```

*Output: [125, 25]*

> Try3:

```
p = '[\d]+[.,\d]+|[\d]*[.][\d]+|[\d]+'
data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'
numbers = []
if re.search(p, data) is not None:
    for catch in re.finditer(p, data):
        numbers.append(catch[0])
print(numbers)
```

*Output: ['122', '125', '55,58,', '25']*

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
import re
data = 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25'

results = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', data)))
print(results)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `\d+` with [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```py
re.findall(r'\d+', 'hs122 125 &55,58, 25')
# ['122', '125', '55', '58', '25']
```